# Using the Enter button to navigate, to next frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I need help, im trying to script together a function that when I press the Enter key that it will navigate to the next frame. I am reallllllllly new to python coding and have only dabbled at it for about 3-4 hours. So far I have the following.

```
from tkinter import *

class App(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    self.parent = parent

    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):

    self.parent.title("Fullscreen Application")

    self.pack(fill="both", expand=True, side="top")

    self.parent.wm_state("zoomed")

    self.parent.bind("<F11>", self.fullscreen_toggle)



    self.fullscreen_toggle()

    self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Program Screen", font=("default",60), fg="black")
    self.label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

def fullscreen_toggle(self, event="none"):

    self.parent.focus_set()
    self.parent.overrideredirect(True)
    self.parent.overrideredirect(False) #added for a toggle effect, not fully sure why it's like this.
    self.parent.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
    self.parent.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)

def fullscreen_next(self, event="none"):

    self.parent.overrideredirect(False)
    self.parent.attributes("-fullscreen", False)
    self.parent.wm_attributes("-topmost", 0)
    self.button = Button(self, text="Next", command=self.func)
    self.button.pack(side='left')
    master.bind('Return', self.func)

def func(self, _event=None):
     self.parent.bind("<Return>", self.fullscreen_next)
     self.centerWindow()
```

Comment: That is it doing when you try? `bind("<Return>", ...)` is the right call.

Comment: I think that works. Ill try to add in a new frame for it to jump to now.

Comment: nope that didnt work , thanks for suggestion though unless im calling the frame incorrectly.

Comment: Please produce a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and let us know what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks adam i think ive got it working now. When i press enter button. Now i just have to get it to go to the frame that im wanting. Ill dabnle with this later today